# Nan returned when checking for third parameter explanation

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

If I call console.log(range(1,10)) I get an array of NaN.  The parameter third is undefined when it enters the first if statement, which evaluates to True.  As the for loop runs, count is added to third which returns NaN.

Why does the loop not stop? Instead, it loops through and adds NaN to the array.

If I set if(typeof third !== 'undefined') third is converted to a string, but how does javascript know to turn third back to number when it runs in the for loop?

```
function range(start,end,third){
  var numberlist = [];
 if(third !== 'undefined'){ 
    if (start < end){
      for (var count = start; count < end; count++){
    numberlist.push(count + third);
    }
  } 
    else {
            for (var count = start; count > end; count--){
    numberlist.push(count + third);
     }
    }
 }
 else {

  for (var count = start; count < (end + 1); count++){
    numberlist.push(count);
    }
 }

  return numberlist;
}
```

Comment: There is no `typeof` in your code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are missing `typeof` operator:

```
 if(typeof third !== 'undefined'){
```

Or, you can check for `undefined`:

```
 if(third !== undefined){
```

The following code will check if the `third` is a string `undefined`:

```
 if(third !== 'undefined'){
```

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` is a primitive, the condition must be `third !== undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from this condition `if (third !== 'undefined'`:

```js
function range(start, end, third) {
  var numberlist = [];
  if (third !== undefined) {
    if (start < end) {
      for (var count = start; count < end; count++) {
        numberlist.push(count + third);
      }
    } else {
      for (var count = start; count > end; count--) {
        numberlist.push(count + third);
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (var count = start; count < (end + 1); count++) {
      numberlist.push(count);
    }
  }

  return numberlist;
}

console.log(range(1, 10))
```

Comment: `if (third)` can be inconsistent. If argument `start` is 0, the condition will result false

Comment: 1) I understand I can set third !== undefined, but why does third !=='undefined' not break the loop? 2) If I set  typeof third !== 'undefined' how does javascript know to convert third back to a number?  I thought typeof converts third to a string.

Comment: @Jahmul14 1.) you're comparing an object with a string. 2.) typeof just get the type of an object. 3.)  typeof doesn't covert to string, it only checks for the type of an object.